# Python/Pandas remove specific string from ending

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove ending 'OF' from a column in the pandas dataframe. I tried 'rstrip', 'split', but it also removes 'O' and 'F', I just need to remove 'OF'. How to do that? Not sure why rstrip removes 'O' and 'F' when I have specifically passed 'OF'.  Sorry if this question was asked before, I just couldn't find one yet. Thanks.

Sample Data:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = ['UNIVERSITY OF CONN. OF','ONTARIO','UNIV. OF TORONTO','ALASKA DEPT.OF']
df = pd.DataFrame({'some_id':l1,'org':l2})
df

some_id org
1       UNIVERSITY OF CONN. OF
2       ONTARIO
3       UNIV. OF TORONTO
4       ALASKA DEPT.OF
```

Tried:

```
df.org.str.rstrip('OF')
# df.org.str.split('OF')[0] # Not what I am looking for
```

Results:

```
0    UNIVERSITY OF CONN. # works
1                  ONTARI # 'O' was removed
2         UNIV. OF TORONT # 'O' was removed
3            ALASKA DEPT. # works
```

Final output needed:

```
0    UNIVERSITY OF CONN. 
1                  ONTARIO
2         UNIV. OF TORONTO
3            ALASKA DEPT.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
df.org = df.org.str.replace('(OF)$','')
```

where `$` indicates the end of string. Or

```
df.org.str.rstrip('(OF)')
```

seems to work as expected.

Output:

```
0    UNIVERSITY OF CONN. 
1                 ONTARIO
2        UNIV. OF TORONTO
3            ALASKA DEPT.
Name: org, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `str.extract`

Capture everything up until, and not including, a single optional `'OF'` at the end of the word. I added a few more rows for test cases.

```
df['extract'] = df.org.str.extract('(.*?)(?=(?:OF$)|$)')

#   some_id                     org               extract
#0        1  UNIVERSITY OF CONN. OF  UNIVERSITY OF CONN. 
#1        2                 ONTARIO               ONTARIO
#2        3        UNIV. OF TORONTO      UNIV. OF TORONTO
#3        4          ALASKA DEPT.OF          ALASKA DEPT.
#4        5            fooOFfooOFOF            fooOFfooOF
#5        6                      fF                    fF
#6        7                   Seven                 Seven
```